# Get PHP session vars in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, session, .htaccess

Is it possible to read the data in the php $_SESSION array in the .htaccess file in Apache? So say I have the following:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

could I then in .htaccess do something like:

```
RewriteRule bla.png folder/{the php session var foo}/file.png
```

Is that possible?

I already have a working workaround but if this is possible it would be way nicer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware that its possible.

But I can think of a few workarounds involving rewriting to a PHP script.

Comment: Yes, rewrite to a PHP script, let PHP output the PNG.

Answer (score 12):

## Answer to the main question:

**No,** at least not as you imagine. The file is called `.ht`***`access`*** because they are *"distributed configuration files"* and of course configuration && ***access*** handling must happen first - therefor you can't get "PHP session variable" because it simply comes after the processing of the `.htaccess`

I will show you some workarounds below, but before - you should **pay attention to this:**

## Is this really necessary? - suggested solutions:

If you just want to redirect filepath **/** by logged-in user - **.htaccess is NOT the way** - use just `bla.php` as address and then in php file do the redirect - something like this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   header("Location: folder/".$_SESSION['foo']."/file.png");
   exit();
?>
```

However if you can't change the source URL, you will first have to redirect `bla.png` to `bla.php` but I guess you know how to do that :-)

In frameworks using MPV/MVC model there are often scripts for "routing" for a reason - e.g. this one.

Optionally you could make a "php-router" from this script adding some other PHP-relying redirects while using `if/elseif/else` or `case` to choose what will happen - where the redirect will go.

#### OR

You are probably using a session anyway - so why just don't generate the url straight in PHP like: 
`$url = "example.com/bla.png?foo=".$_SESSION['foo'];` + regexp in `.htaccess` or even:

`$url = "example.com/folder/".$_SESSION['foo']."/file.png";`

Anyway I guess you are redirecting because you can't (for some reason) do that. :-)

## Workarounds

If you are still persuaded that you have to do this in .htaccess file here are some workarounds

### 1) Use cookies

In modern days cookies are often available, so if you "trust" your client's cookies, you could make a redirect rule based on a `HTTP_COOKIE` server-variable - assuming you've stored cookie called "`foo`" before:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*)foo=([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)$ [NC]        
RewriteRule ^bla.png$ /folder/%2/file.png [R=307,NC,L] 
#possibly use 302 if you like dinosaurs
```

As you can see the trick is to create condition checking `HTTP_COOKIE` server-variable for some condition. It basicly says:

> Is there a COOKIE called "foo" which contains only "-, _, lower or upper case letters or numbers"?
>   
> If so - redirect *example.com/bla.png* to *example.com/folder/CURRENT_FOO_VALUE/file.png*
>   
> **[flags]**: [307 redirect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (R=307), don't mind letter-case (NC), don't apply other rules (L)

Good point is that `HTTP_COOKIE` server-variable is structured in this way:

```
name=value; name2=value2
```

### 2) NOT recommended - other workarounds:

#### a) read session to `HTTP_SESSION` environment variable using mod_session

See the [apache manual for mod_session](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_session.html) for more info how to read session into the `HTTP_SESSION` env. variable. The approach then would be the same as for the "COOKIE-workaround".

#### b) store needed info in a text file and read it with the `RewriteMap` directive as @Chris suggested

But again you will somehow have to detect which 'foo' is it so maybe `SSL_SESSION_ID` or some other `$_GET/$_POST` parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is something that you could do easily. You could read the PHPSESSID using something like %{HTTP_COOKIE} in your .htaccess, but in order to get access to the actual data in the session PHP is doing a lot of extra work, so you would have to somehow re-implement that (i.e. reading the data from wherever it is stored, de-serializing etc.)

Comment: This is the correct answer - if you want session data in your htaccess, you have to write it to a cookie first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will apply to your particular problem or not but RewriteMap is a very useful and often over-looked directive for mod_rewrite.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

If you can pre-compute your session variables or store them to a text file (maybe when they get set) the map entries can be easily retrieved based on any of the available request details.

Otherwise, you could put together a simple external mapper (probably, a PHP script as that'd be easiest) that uses the sessionid to determine the value of the session variable and returns the proper URL for the rewrite rule to use.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that the way you want.

If you are really using the $_SESSION variable maybe there's an Apache environmental variable that you can use that will have the same value as the $_SESSION one.

Look at the following list and see if any of them helps:
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/env_var.htm

You'll have to use it like this:

> RewriteRule bla.png
>   folder/%{VAR_NAME}/file.png